# How to save a sns.facetgrid to a pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'occasions': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'val':[1,1,1,2]})
```

I am trying to create a histogram with a facet using seaborn like this and I want to save that image to a pdf, so i am doing this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

pdf = PdfPages('exploration.pdf')
g = sns.FacetGrid(foo, col="occasions", margin_titles=True)
g.map(plt.hist,'val', color="steelblue")
g.set_titles(col_template = '{col_name}')
g.fig.suptitle('title')
plot_fig(g, pdf)
```

where

```
def plot_fig(plot, pdf):
    try:
        fig = plot.draw()
    except:
        fig = plot
    pdf.savefig(fig, height=10, width=18, dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5)
    plt.close()
```

But I get an error: `ValueError: No figure <seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid object at 0x7f1ca2300780>`, any ideas why and how I could fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your `PdfPages('exploration.pdf')` file looks like, thus I'cant make sure that this works, but in general saving figures should work like this:

```
def plot_fig(plot, pdf):
    try:
        fig = plot.draw()
    except:
        fig = plot
    pdf.savefig(fig.fig, height=10, width=18, dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5)
    plt.close()
```

What is called `fig` in your function is the `seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid`. To access the underlying `matplotlib.figure` and use its `savefig` method, you need to select it using `fig.fig`. Maybe renaming the facet grid to something else than `fig` might help reducing the confusion.